# Is there a way to get the thrown error message using `try?` is Swift?

Tags: swift, error-handling, try-catch

Using `do-catch` returns the thrown error message in the `catch` block:

```
do {
  data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
} catch {
  print(error) // Using `error`
}
```

Is it possible to access `error` using `try?`:

```
guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { /* access error here */ }
```

Comment: No, that is exactly what you threw away by saying `try?`. If you don't want to lose the error, don't do that.

Comment: No, you use `try?` when you don’t care about the actual error that gets thrown. The result is either nil and you handle the error in the same way no matter what kind of error happened, or it is not nil because no error was thrown.

Comment: @danielhadar I'm not sure, I think it's a fairly good question. The only thing I would change to it is to add in the problem you're trying to solve with this. Are you settling a mere curiosity? Is there some other reason why the `do`/`catch` has some unpleasant consequences you're trying to mitigate by using `guard`? etc.

Comment: @Alexander The difference between `do-catch` and `try?` is that in the first, code that uses `data` should also be set within the `do` block (or define `var data: Data` outside, but eww).

Comment: @danielhadar If the `catch` block returns or breaks scope in some other way (as would be necessary in a `guard`'s `else` statement, anyway), then Swift's definite initialization logic can handle that. Declare data as `let data: Data`, assign to it in the `do` block, exit the scope in the `catch` block, and you can access `data` after the `catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. `try?` explicitly converts it to an optional, losing the error object along the way.

You *could* use the `Result` type instead to try to achieve your goal syntax, but it soon becomes pretty clear that your original code is best:

```
extension Result {
    var payload: Success? {
        switch self {
            case .success(let payload): return payload
            case .failure(_): return nil
        }
    }

    var error: Failure? {
        switch self {
            case .success(_): return nil
            case .failure(let error): return error
        }
    }
}


let result = Result(catching: { Data(contentsOf: url) })
guard let data = result.payload else { print(result.error!) }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to **[The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html#ID542)**:

> You use `try?` to handle an error by converting it to an `optional` value.
>   If an error is thrown while evaluating the `try?` expression, the value
>   of the expression is `nil`.

So the answer is **NO** for now. But there are some proposals in the Swift community asking for **guard/catch** feature and it may be available later.